# upload image to parse.com and save it in the database

Tags: javascript, file, parse-platform

I have signup form and there i want let the user upload his image.

this is the js where i try to upload to parse.com:
I get alert of code 100. (there is no problem connectin parse.com since regular signup  work good)

```
var fileUploadControl = $("#img1")[0];
if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {
  var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
  var name = "photo.png";

  var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);

  parseFile.save().then(function() {
  // The file has been saved to Parse.
  var url = parseFile.url();


  user.set("img", url);


}, function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);

  // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
});
}
```

this is the html where "img1" declare

```
<form dir="rtl" class="form-container" id="signUp_form" method='post'>
.........................
......................
<input type="file" name="img1" size="40"  id="img1" onchange="readURL(this);">
<img id="blah" src="empty-f.gif" alt="your image" width="150px" height="150px" />
</form>
```

and if it is relevant :

```
  function readURL(input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {

                $('#blah')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the user img column is a pointer to an image object you need to set the value to the image object rather than the url.

```
user.set("img", parseFile);
```